# asymmetric key creation over network

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, assemblies, public-key

I'm attempting to [add an assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx) to a database in SQL2008 using an [asymmetric key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174430.aspx).

We're adding the assembly using a hex string (adding assemblies to servers through sql queries only)

```
USE [master] 
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.asymmetric_keys where name = 'ManagedAsymmetricKey')
 BEGIN
  CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ManagedAsymmetricKey FROM FILE = 'C:\Managed.dll'
  CREATE LOGIN CLRLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY ManagedAsymmetricKey
  GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO CLRLogin
 END
GO

USE [$dbName]
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Managed]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A....
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

This will work on a local instance however over the network we receive; 
`The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file does not exist or has invalid format.`

I may be assuming wrongly that I should be adding the key first, should I be adding the assembly then doing something along the lines of `CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ManagedAsymmetricKey FROM ASSEMBLY [workingDB].[dbo].[Managed]` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following steps to get it working:

- run your create assembly statement with SAFE permission_set (even if the assembly needs UNSAFE for execution)
- create the asymmetric key from the assembly
- drop your assembly
- create a login from the asymmetric key
- grant the login unsafe assembly rights

  ```
  CREATE ASSEMBLY [Managed]
  AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
  FROM 0x4D5A....
  WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE

  CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ManagedAsymmetricKey FROM ASSEMBLY [Managed]

  DROP ASSEMBLY [Managed]

  CREATE LOGIN CLRLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY ManagedAsymmetricKey

  GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO CLRLogin
  ```

Comment: For the temporary assembly , you do not need to set `PERMISSION_SET` to `UNSAFE`, because you do not need to execute code from the assembly to create the key. That also means that you don't have to set `TRUSTWORTHY` anywhere. Besides that, thanks for the clever hack!

Comment: I put unsafe because the assembly in the question is unsafe. if you have a safe assembly this is indeed not needed.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I don't think that assemblies are inherently (un)safe. My assembly contains code that only runs with `UNSAFE` permissions, but SQL Server does not complain when I create the assembly with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`.

Comment: So `CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY` works even if the assembly only has `SAFE` permissions. After that, you can use the asymmetric key (and associated login) to change the permission set to `UNSAFE`. I've tested it and it works for me. I didn't need to make the master database trustworthy.

Comment: I updated the script based on the SAFE permission_set approach

Answer (score 2):

The `FROM FILE =` is always from the perspective of SQL Server.  You would have copy the certificate to a local drive on the database server.