# Key Exchange between SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, security, diffie-hellman

I have to implement "secure communication" between two Microsoft SQL servers. "Communication" in this case is an asynchronous high-latency operation and I have to work with the least possible amount of round trips. There is no shared secret available between the two servers, and no secure channel. The communication equipment does not support secure transmission.

(I know that under these circumstances I can't prevent against active MitM attacks, but that's above my paygrade, I just want to get everything else right.)

SQL Server allows for builtin AES256 encryption/decryption which I want to use, just that I have to make a key exchange beforehand.

I thought to use some builtin DHKE, since it is always better not to implement anything security-related by myself. **Has SQL Server builtin DHKE functions, or can I setup SQL server to reliably support DHKE? Is there any other option I should look for?**

Comment: How are the SQL Servers communicating with each other? If this is a linked server setup that mechanic supports transport encryption already.  VPN would be another alternative.

Comment: @AlexK. The servers are not part of the same environment. They cannot communicate directly, one of them cannot reach the internet by itself. They are "communicating" over multiple hops with applications in different languages (bashscript, Fortran and C#, to name a few), and different formats/protocols, including but not limited to sending/processing email and copying/replicating binary files between multiple systems.

Comment: So it's not a case of one SQL server communicating with another directly? If so is this not a question about how to secure transport between whatever applications you have that do the communication as opposed to securing the TDS stream itself?

Comment: @AlexK. I could possibly secure the transmission for every hop; I just guessed it should be a little bit easier to implement end-to-end security, the two ends being Microsoft SQL servers.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't set up an asymmetric key on each server and export the public keys? There are built-in functions for such things native to SQL…

Comment: @BenThul I guess that's what I meant with "any other option". I tried to understand MSDN documentation of CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY, but failed. Will work through other docs, hoping to get a grasp. Nevertheless, if you have any experience that could spare me hours of trial and error, I'd appreciate if you could type together an answer. The matter [seems to be a bit complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059912/asymmetric-key-creation-over-network).